# How can i stop ffmpeg screen recording correctly?

Tags: ffmpeg, shutdown

I am recording my screen and saving it to a *.mkv container (I am not sure it is what i really need, i have chosen it because a matadata in start of the file, and had hoped the file will be OK if simething will be wrong) using command:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 7 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -vcodec png -f segment -segment_time 20 Video_%02d.mkv
```

I have problem: When a shut down my pc, using the hardware button :), i have 0 size video file segment, i don't know why it happens.

Comment: What is your OS/distro?

Answer (score 2):

You should press Q while running the command. This is the designed way of quitting ffmpeg.

Or you can kill the ffmpeg process with SIGINT, if you cannot access its standard input.

Comment: I need a way to do it without pressing q key, for example when when the computer shuts down incorrectly

Comment: A forceful shutdown is a nasty thing to do to a running process... so you have to add an ffmpeg option to `fsync()` the output file periodically, I don't know how to do it.