# How to reduce noise and cancell echo for WebRTC in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, webrtc

We are building an application for recoding Video messages via the Open WebRTC and while we record the message we are facing some the reverberations of the nearby microphones and electronic devices.

Please assist.

Comment: once the user finishes the recording, is it sent to a server ? if yes, you could explore ffmpeg conversion and filters => there is good stuff on noise filtering and noise reduction...

Comment: We are facing  the issue while recording

Comment: There could be different reasons : empty rooms have tendency to have more echo, microphones with auto-volume could also be problematic, because, if detects low sound it will automatically pump up the gain and thus pumping echo too....

Comment: I use openvidu and it's very good https://openvidu.io/ see also this (take the time to read the question AND the answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837454/ffmpeg-x11grab-to-streamable-format and this for HLS player https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926044/hls-js-starting-a-beginning-with-android-mobile-chrome-webview-also-and-not-l